# IE8 javascript error onmouseover error

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, magento

Managed to finally get our slider working perfectly, although a prototype error still remains which is apparently the norm at current.

However when you hover over the "home" button on the category bar another error is displayed in IE8:

```
Message: Object expected
Line: 111
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://foscam-uk.com/index.php
```

The code for this is:

```
<li class="home css3" 
    onmouseout="toggleMenu(this,0)" 
    onmouseover="toggleMenu(this,1)">
    <a href="http://foscam-uk.com/" title="Home">
        <span>Home</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Update:
Thanks guys, the javascript file was not being called. Now it is this has created more errors in the form of:

Message: 'className' is null or not an object

Message: 'length' is null or not an object

If anyone could assist that would be great. Thanks

```
function toggleMenu(el, over)
{
    if (over) {
        Element.addClassName(el, 'over');
    }
    else {
        Element.removeClassName(el, 'over');
     }
}
```

Comment: Post the code for `toggleMenu` too? Obviously the error is not in the code you posted.

Comment: Yes the problem is related to toggleMenu not being declared or missing. If you check on other browsers you get the same error, its not just IE8.

Answer (score 2):

As the errors indicate:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'toggleMenu' is undefined 
index.php, line 111 character 1
```

You're calling `toggleMenu`, but you don't have a function by that name. This isn't IE-related either, as the same error can be seen in Chrome. A missing function is a missing function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, this was actually a purchased template so should have come with it. I have contacted them to ask about this, thanks you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what FF reports:

Timestamp: 6/8/2012 9:54:02 AM
Error: toggleMenu is not defined
Source File: http://foscam-uk.com/index.php
Line: 1

So either you forgot to link that js file or you forgot to write that function at all...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, this was actually a purchased template so should have come with it. I have contacted them to ask about this, thanks you once again.